# How can I access specific index in a list at a particular key inside a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary

I created a dictionary like this:

```
var sortedDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, List<double>>();
```

I have now multiple values (list) at any particular datetime key.

If I need to access specific value at any DATETIME key, how can I get to it?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dictionary lookups are *usually* cheap, and for DateTime keys they are, but MSDN points out [The speed of retrieval depends on the quality of the hashing algorithm of the type specified for TKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx).  Also note that lookups approach O(1), but for very large dictionaries accessed frequently *approaches* might just warrant avoiding a double lookup.

So, in the interest of completeness:

```
int i = 42; // Or whatever index you want to look up
DateTime date = DATE_YOU_WANT_HERE;

List<double> valuesForDate;

bool foundDate = sortedDict.TryGetValue(date, out valuesForDate);
if (foundDate)
{
    double theValue = valuesForDate[i];
}
else
{
    // Whatever you need to do if there is no key for your date
}
```

Comment: missing an `i` assignment?

Answer (score 2):

I'd recommend an approach like the following given a key of `utcNow` and index `i`:

```
List<double> vals;
if(sortedDict.TryGetValue(utcNow, out vals)) {
  double val = vals[i];
}
```

This will avoid the double index lookup on the dictionary, and clearly communicates the intent (this value might or might not be in there)

Comment: Lookups on dictionaries are cheap. That's the point of using them.

Comment: They are *usually* cheap, and for DateTime keys they are, but MSDN points out `The speed of retrieval depends on the quality of the hashing algorithm of the type specified for TKey.`  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508(v=vs.110).aspx  Also note that lookups approach O(1), but for very large dictionaries accessed frequently *approaches* might just warrant avoiding a double lookup.

Answer (score 1):

Given your key `date`, and an index of `i`, this is simple:

```
var value = sortedDict[date][i];
```

This is assuming the key exists in the dictionary. If there is a possibility that it doesn't, then you should check first.

```
if (sortDict.ContainsKey(date)) 
{
    var value = sortedDict[date][i];
}
```

When you access your `Dictionary<S,T>` with a key of type `S`, what you get back is an object of type `T`. In your case, `T` is a `List<double>`.

If you wanted to extract the index `i` for *all* keys in your dictionary (because rereading the question, I'm not sure that wasn't what you were trying to get at), then this is pretty simple:

```
var allI = sortedDict.Select(k => k.Value[i]).ToList();
```

But this assumes that `i` is present in all the key values. If not, you'd need to check for that too:

```
var allI = sortedDict.Where(k => i < k.Value.Length ).Select(k => k.Value[i]).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Matt! Works for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow; //example DateTime
if (sortedDict.ContainsKey(utcNow))
{
    foreach (double listItem in sortedDict[utcNow])
    {
        //manipulate listItem here
    }
}
```

Edit: Looks like I misunderstood the question; I thought that you wanted to iterate through the values of a `List<Double>` of a particular `DateTime` key in `sortedDict`. Solutions such as the ones by [Eric J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482309/4302070) and [Matt Burland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31482118/4302070) are better ways to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

To get a specific VALUE from a list use List.Find().
To get the list INDEX of a specific value use List.FindIndex().
See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx for a list of all List members.